# gltf viewer does not display full dae model after COLLADA2GLTF conversion

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax, collada, gltf

I have a `.dae` model [here](http://xuchen81.github.io/img/Archive.zip) , and I use latest version of https://github.com/KhronosGroup/COLLADA2GLTF to convert this dae file into a `gltf 2.0` file.

```
./COLLADA2GLTF-bin -i /path/to/Archive/Bayleef_ColladaMax.DAE  -o ~/test.gltf -v 2.0 --doubleSided true --preserveUnusedSemantics true
```

However when I view it on gltf online viewer https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/, it only displays something like tree branches.

the actual dae model:

[image]

gltfloader displays after the conversion:

[image]

babylonjs and blender loaded the glTF display just like the bad image above

Comment: Can you load the converted `glTF` file in other viewers or software? Please test with the Babylon.js sandbox (https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) and Blender (https://www.blender.org/).

Comment: Looks like the bones/armature system is causing problems somehow.

Comment: @Mugen87 thanks for your comment. I tried both babylonjs and blender and it looks just the same with the `bad` image.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you file at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/COLLADA2GLTF/. In the meantime, you can change your workflow and use Blender for the conversion. Blender can import Collada files and export to `glTF`.